# set `ulimit -c` from outside shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, ulimit

I have a program that's running automatically on boot, and sporadically causing a coredump.

I'd like to record the output, but I can't seem to set `ulimit -c` programmatically (It's defaulted to 0, and resets every time).

I've tried using a bash script, as well as python's `sh`, `os.system` and `subprocess`, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: what happened when you tried subprocess?

Comment: Have you added `ulimit -c` to your program's start script?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A process may only set resource limits for itself and its children. It cannot set resource limits for its ancestor. By calling `os.system('ulimit -c')`, you are asking the child "ulimit" process to set the resource limit of the ancestor "Python" process.

Your Python program can set its resource limit using the [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) module:

```
import resource

resource.setrlimit(
    resource.RLIMIT_CORE,
    (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I didn't know about the resource module. Tested and works perfectly :) Now to wait for coredumps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your problem is that you haven't understood that `rlimit`s are set per process. If you use `os.system` in Python to call ulimit, that is only going to set the ulimit in that newly spawned shell process, which then immediately exits after which nothing has been changed.

What you need to do, instead, is to run `ulimit` in the shell that starts your program. The process your program is running in will then inherit that rlimit from the shell.

I do not think there is any way to alter the rlimit of process X from process Y, where X != Y.

**EDIT**: I'll have to take that last back, at least in case you're running in Linux. There is a Linux-specific syscall `prlimit` that allows you to change the rlimits of a different process, and it also does appear to be available in Python's `resource` module, though it is undocumented there. See the manpage `prlimit(2)` instead; I'd assume that the function available in Python uses the same arguments.

Answer (score 2):

To throw another solution into the mix - I globally set the ulimit in debian using limits.conf:

```
grep -q -F '* soft core 100000' /etc/security/limits.conf || echo '* soft core 100000' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
grep -q -F 'root hard core 100000' /etc/security/limits.conf || echo 'root hard core 100000' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

This was also possible using the `os.system` command in python.

Comment: Note that changes to `limits.conf` take effect at the begining of your **next** login session.